# MD5 hashing Java Quiz

Tags: java, hash

This question is a part of a quiz which I've been attending.

Q: Pushing a string through a hash function is easy. If you go forwards.How about backwards? This might require a bit more force. Maybe even brute force?
The next password consists of three characters [a-z,A-Z,0-9].The md5-hash of the password begins with 19acf8371f.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class Festo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String number = "0123456789";
        int count = 1;
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        for (int j = 65; j < 65 + 26; j++) {
            char val = (char) j;
            for (int k = 97; k < 97 + 26; k++) {
                char val1 = (char) k;
                for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
                    String input = val1 + "" + val + i;
                    byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());
                    BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
                    String hashtext = no.toString(16);
                    while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
                        hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
                    }
                    System.out.println(input + " " + hashtext + " " + count++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This hash(19acf8371f) is not found in this output. Can any one point out what is wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: Their `[a-z,A-Z,0-9]` doesn't look like it implies which position has the lowercase, uppercase or digit, like you've done in your code.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for the hint. I've solved this. A: 5Kt.